# Shell's "read" command in an elisp script

Tags: shell-command

How can I get the shell's read command working (prompting for the input) in an elisp script? I have

```
(shell-command "read -s-p \"Enter Password: \" PASSWORD")
```

but it doesn't prompt anything.

Comment: Do you want to get an password in elisp? Then you may want to use `read-password`, see [Reading a Password](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Reading-a-Password.html) for documentation.

Comment: @theldoria Thank you. I'd like also to learn how to call little pieces of interactive shell script in elisp scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not that easy, because `shell-command` and `start-process` do not define an INPUT stream. `call-process` just operates on file input.

Emacs documentation states how to feed input to processes, [see here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Input-to-Processes.html).

Eventually you have to do something like this:

```
(defun endless/send-input (input &optional nl)
    "Send INPUT to the current process.
Interactively also sends a terminating newline."
    (interactive "MInput: \nd")
    (let ((string (concat input (if nl "\n"))))
        ;; This is just for visual feedback.
        (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
            (insert-before-markers string))
        ;; This is the important part.
        (process-send-string
         (start-process "rete" "*rete*" "bash" "-c" "read foo; echo $foo")
         string)))
```

Evaluate and call this function. After inputting some keys and `<enter>`, have a look at buffer `*rete*`.

*Note:* `read` is a so called shell internal command. This means there exists no binary (i.e. `/bin/read` or `/usr/bin/read`). You need to call a shell (in this example `bash`) to use `read`.

*Note:* This code does not hide user input like your password example. You should not copy passwords with methods like this, imho this is highly insecure.

*Note:* big part of this code is shamelessly stolen from [Endless Parentheses](http://endlessparentheses.com/provide-input-to-the-compilation-buffer.html).